# Tabhost listener timing issue

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I've got a tabhost as the main screen of my app and it works great and I've been using it for awhile now.  Each tab is a separate Activity, by the way.

The problem is, I need to know when a user has clicked on a tab, and I need to know that before the Activity is shown on the screen.  I was pretty quickly able to get it to work where I can find out when the user clicks on a Tab, but I'm not finding that out until AFTER the Activity has already filled the screen.

Can you think of any creative ways to know that the tab has changed in the tabhost BEFORE the Activity content associated with that Tab is shown?

Comment: If you really want to dig into it, for the purposes of this question the code here is basically the code I'm working with as the framework of my tabhost:  [link](http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/11/17/tablayouttabhost-tutorial-for-android-reusing-layout/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try extending and TabWidget and override the onFocusChange method to something like:

```
public class MyTabWidget extends TabWidget{
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        doSomethingBefore();
        super.onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus);
        doSomethingAfter();
    }
    void doSomethingAfter {
        ...
    }
    void doSomethingBefore{ 
        ...
    }
}
```

then reference that fully qualified class in your xml and you should be g2g.

Comment: Sounds promising, but how would that fit with the code in the link posted under the first comment?

Comment: What does the reference to the class above look like in my layout file containing the tabwidget?

Comment: change <TabWidget .../>  to <com.package.name.of.whatever.package.is.named.MyTabWidget .../>